# How much faster is copying files though TeraCopy vs. Windows 7 native copy function?

Tags: windows-7, teracopy

Teracopy's [official page](http://codesector.com/teracopy) says "TeraCopy uses dynamically adjusted buffers to reduce the seek times.".

Wikipedia [points to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCopy) some tests:

> In a test conducted in 2008 by lifehacker, Fastcopy was several times
>   faster than it's rival Teracopy, a program with similar functionality.
>   However, both programs have been updated since then. A more extensive
>   comparison was performed between TeraCopy v2.07beta, KillCopy v2.85,
>   FastCopy v1.99r4, SuperCopier v2.2bet and published on a forum in
>   2009.

I'm looking for more recent speed tests on Windows 7.

Comment: How about testing it yourself?

Comment: @gronostaj  Thank you I haven't thought of that. Also I totally disagree the closure of the question: my question is not about recommendation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With lots of small files, [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) (native) works just as well as teracopy.

Teracopy can handle larger files a little bit better according to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/73887/battle-of-the-file-copiers-windows-teracopy-and-supercopier/).

Here is another [unverified benchmarking](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1337937&#r4) with pictures!

I use robocopy and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have been using TC for two years now, on Win7 x64.
Never had any "real" troubles with it. It's faster, yet I don't have exact information.

There's a bug in there somewhere, sporadically shutting down the process before it even starts, fixable by restarting TC a few (insert random number) times, till it works.
It never quits in the middle, only when a Paste-command is made.

For the harder times, I've enabled the Scroll-Lock feature, to toggle between Windows' service, and TC.